# Skype For Business URL (SIP)

Tags: skype-for-business

To initiate a chat in Skype for Business, we can use:

```
<a href="sips:xyz@domain.com">Open Skype Business</a>
```

However, is it possible to have open the window and pre-populate it with text - like we would if we use a mailto we can set the subject by using

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Suggestions">Email</a>
```